# Getting error in Hibernate query. Error: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to implement many-to-one relationship in SpringMvc model class. But i am not able to find any example from which i could able to understand how this work.

```
return (Student_Course) session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student_Course as sc where c.user.id=?").setInteger(0, user_id).uniqueResult()
```

In above code i am trying to retreive Student_Course table from database through hibernate query but it is giving me this error.

**Error**

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'c.user.id' [from com.sanjay31321.sys.model.Student_Course as sc where c.user.id=?]
```

Is there any other way i can write this hql query so i can get this table. Please help me.

**Course Class :**

```
@Entity @Table (name="Course")
public class Course {
    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="course_name")
    private String name;

    //Setter and Getter
}
```

**Student_Course Class:**

```
@Entity @Table (name="Student_course")
public class Student_Course {

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
    private Course course;

    //Setter and Getter
}
```

**User Class:**

```
@Entity @Table (name="user")
public class User {

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="email")  @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password") 
    private String password;

    //Setter and Getter
}
```

**StudentCourseDaoImpl Class**

```
@Repository
public class StudentCourseDaoImpl implements StudentCourseDao{

    @Autowired private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public Student_Course getStudentCourseByUserID(int user_id) {
        return (Student_Course) session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student_Course as sc where c.user.id=?").setInteger(0, user_id).uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alias name is `sc`, your column name is `user_id`, so it should be

```
"from Student_Course as sc where sc.user_id=?"
```

instead.

Comment: try to do it like following

Comment: It is working..I made a mistake there...Thank you very much friend.